# How to insert multiple icons?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert multiple star icons right under the review text, is there any ways to do so?

I have tried using pseudo elements in order to paste the icons, but it's only able to insert just 1 icon when multiple icons are needed to be inserted.
So far I have tried:

```
.review::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900; content: "\f007";
}
```

```css
.circle {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  right: 245px;
}

.namedetails {
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.review {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.review::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900; content: "\f007";
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<p class="namedetails">Name Surname</p>
<span class="review">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In dictum non consectetur a. Turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi. Mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum. Id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor!</span>
```

I expect for 5 star icons to appear right under the review text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You say you _expect for 5 star icons to appear right under the review text._ yet there is nothing in your code that would produce/output stars.

Comment: Yeah, well I tried and deleted the code that would produce the stars, I'm not this experienced yet and it would only produce 1 star when 5 are needed,

Comment: Update your answer with what you tried. It's better for us to see what isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the latest CDN from font-awesome to produce this result:

The only change I made to your snippet code was to make the `.review span` into a paragraph in order to make a small space underneath the text for the stars.  If you want less whitespace then simply revert to `<span>` instead of `<p>`.

```css
i.far { margin-right: .2rem;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title> SO Answer </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
  
        
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <p class="namedetails">Name Surname</p>
    <p class="review">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In dictum non consectetur a. Turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi. Mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum. Id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor!</p>

    <span><i class="far fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i></span>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see, is there any way to space out the stars using CSS?

Comment: I have added CSS to this snippet to create space between the stars _ You can adjust the space to suit your needs `i.far { margin-right: .2rem;}` _ I hope it helps and thanks for the upvote

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using some free Awesome Fonts icon. One way to handle icons addition is using `<i>` tag provided by the same website. First, you need to add a CDN link inside `<head>` tag on your html, to reference js file provided by Awesome Fonts:

```
<head>
   ...
   <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also, you can dig into another ways to add the file into your project in the [start page](https://fontawesome.com/start).

Then, put your `<i>` tag icon inside your `<spam>` element.

```
<span class="review">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet! <i class="fas fa-star"></i> 
</span>
```

The browser will render it like a svg element. You can find the free icon [here](https://fontawesome.com/icons/star?style=solid).